# How to run while(true) loop without freezing Windows form in C#?

Tags: c#, kinect

I am writing an application that should show tracked skeletons from up to 4 Kinects. The tracking and then drawing on the form should start when the user presses the `Start` button. Coming from a Java background I know little about using `delegates` and `EventHandlers` in C#. So far my code looks like this, but it freezes the form completely. How to fix that?

```
private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProgramLoop();
}

private void ProgramLoop()
{
    int sensorCount = 0;
    foreach (KinectSensor connectedSensor in KinectSensor.KinectSensors)
    {
        if (connectedSensor.Status == KinectStatus.Connected)
        {
            connectedSensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
            connectedSensorsArray.Add(connectedSensor);
            connectedSensor.Start();
            sensorCount++;
        }
    }
}

private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    trackSkeletons();
}

private void trackSkeletons()
{
    while (true)
    {
        foreach (KinectSensor sensor in connectedSensorsArray)
        {
            SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = sensor.SkeletonStream.OpenNextFrame(200);
            if (skeletonFrame != null)
            {
                if (initSkeletons == null)
                {
                    initSkeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
                }
                skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(initSkeletons);
                skeletonFrame.Dispose();
                Skeleton initSkeleton = initSkeletons.Where(s => s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked).FirstOrDefault();
                if (initSkeleton != null)
                {
                    switch (connectedSensorsArray.IndexOf(sensor))
                    {
                        case 0:
                            mainQueue.Enqueue(initSkeleton);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            secondQueue.Enqueue(initSkeleton);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            thirdQueue.Enqueue(initSkeleton);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            fourthQueue.Enqueue(initSkeleton);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //dequeue Skeletons and draw them
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use Threads, simple to do in C# but you need to know how to work with threads to not cause problems related to threading

Comment: Use the `SkeletonFrameReady` Event there is no need for a while true and no need for threads. Have a look at [Tracking Users with Kinect Skeletal Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131025.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you should use a timer instead of a `while(true)`.

your timer will be executed every X sec and when he is called, you can call your own function `trackSkeletons()`.

Answer (score 0):

As i said you need to use threads, i dont exactly know how kinect sdk works but it should be fine like this as long as trackSkeletons() doesnt write into data that another thread is using else you need to solve that problem with some sort of synchronization. But i think it should work like this

```
private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(trackSkeletons);
    thread.Start();
}
```

And in trackSkeletons you can add a sleep for some miliseconds right at the end of the while (but still in it)

```
while(true)
{
    //code
    Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you need a break condition to stop the tracking.

Also you need to use threads if you don't want to freeze your UI.

For the thread it is quite simple:

```
Thread t = new Thread(trackSkeletons);
t.Start();
```

Now in your class, you should add a private boolean field `_trackSkeletons` so your click event becomes like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(trackSkeletons);
_trackSkeletons = true;
t.Start();
```

And in your trackSkeletons method, use:

```
while(_trackSkeletons)
{
   ....
}
```

This lets you stop the thread when you need it (perhaps by a click on a "Stop" button).
The `Thread.Sleep` method suggested by Vajura also can be useful.

One last thing that is important to know when using threads in a Winform application: you can't directly change any user interface element from your thread, otherwise you'll get an exception. You need to use the `Invoke` methods to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Need Threads like this ;

```
 private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Thread t = new Thread(trackSkeletons);
    t.Start();
    }
```

Help:  [Threads](http://www.dotnetperls.com/thread)

Answer (score -1):

```
    async void trackSkeletons() 
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
             
           // your code here
            

        }

    }
```